# Socket.io in node.js becoming irresponsive after some time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I am trying to use websockets to dynamically update the list of currently online members on my website. When the client gets connected in addition of maintaining an array of currently online members I am also updating the 'online_users' table in mysql database. I am using socket.io with express framework to implement websockets. 
When i run the server the server runs well for some time and then becomes irresponsive.
Could anyone help me with what is going wrong in my code.

```
    //global variables
var onlineUsers={};
var onlineUsersId=[];
var noOfUsers=0;
//mysql
var mysql     =    require('mysql');

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, 
    host     : '**********',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '******',
    database : 'users_info',
    debug    :  false
});

exports.addUsers =function(socket){

socket.on('addUser',function(data){
if(onlineUsersId.indexOf(data.userId)==-1){
onlineUsersId.push(data.userId);
data.connection=socket;
onlineUsers[noOfUsers]=data;
noOfUsers++;
//entering data into database......
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
       if (err) {
        connection.release();
        }  

       var post={user_id:data.userId, username: data.username};     
        connection.query("INSERT INTO online_users SET ?",post,function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
           if(err){
                connection.release();
            }        
        });           
  });
console.log(onlineUsersId);
}
});


socket.on('disconnect',function(){
var i=0;
while(onlineUsers[i]){
if(onlineUsers[i].connection.id===socket.id){
    var userId=onlineUsers[i].userId;
    var username=onlineUsers[i].username;
    //removing data from database......
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var post={user_id:userId};
         connection.query("DELETE FROM online_users WHERE user_id = "+ post.user_id,function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
        });
  });
onlineUsersId.splice(onlineUsersId.indexOf(userId),1);
delete onlineUsers[i];
noOfUsers--;
//releasing listeners
console.log(onlineUsersId);
break;
}
i++;
}
})
}
```

Comment: *runs for some time* ... How long is "some time?"  15 minutes? 8 hours? 3 weeks?  Also, `if (err) {...` don't you think you might want to log those, as well as logging what happens right before you invoke a function and again inside the function's callback?  In one case, above, it looks like you will try to release a connection twice on error, not sure what that might do but seems like bad practice.

Comment: It runs for 2-3 minutes before becoming irresponsive. Initially i was printing the error but as far as mysql is considered there were no errors.

Comment: I modified the code such that it releases the connection once on error but still having the same problem.

Comment: onlineUsers[noOfUsers]=data;
noOfUsers++;

Comment: I modified the onlineUsers[noOfUsers]=data;  to   onlineUsers["user"+data.userId]=data  which seems to have solved the problem. Earlier i was using a single variable "noOfUsers" to build the onlineUsers object as well as store the total no of online users. So when I was removing the disconnected sockets from the online users object the server was geting stuck there.